# is it possible to type in a cell that has a formula in it without deleting what the formula does to that cell?

Tags: formula, cell

Is it possible to be able to type in a cell that already has a formula in it?

I'll go into a bit more detail here

The cell in question has a formula in it that when another sheet has a value typed in it is matched with the result into the said cell.

Is it possible type in this cell with text but keeping the formula so when the cell is blank the formula stays and still displays the result?

Comment: Why is the tag `excel` missing? (if this is about Excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you are asking for, but you can have some VBA code that will replace the formula back in a cell every time it is cleared.

you would do this using the `Worksheet_Change` event ([MS Docs page here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)). Every time the worksheet the code below is in (assumed to be `Sheet1`) is changed, it will check if any of the changed cells are in the range `C1:C10` and, if they are empty, enter a formula that refers to the same cell address in `sheet2` in that cell.

If you want to use this, you will need to alter the code so it affects the cells you want it to, and provides the formula you are actually looking for (as you dont say what either of those are).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("C1:C10")) 'change the range address here to control which cells are affected by the change
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cll In Target
        If IsEmpty(cll) Then
            cll.Formula = "=Sheet2!" & cll.Address 'change this line 
        End If
    Next cll

End Sub
```